# Как сделать блок этой формы?

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Скиньте пожалуйста код примера подобного блока, дальше сам додумаю уже )

Comment: интересует именно уголок от блока, так как он с продолжением фона и довольно нестандартной формы

Answer (score 0):

Самое простое

```
<img src="фон с хвостиком.png" style="background-image:photo.jpg" />
```

В `фон с хвостиком.png` фигурная прозрачность :-)

Answer (score 0):

Самое простое это воспользоваться SVG, в моём случае я взял редактор svg: inkscape и открыл ваше изображение, обвёл обычным инструментом по созданию path и скопировал на новую картинку и сделал clip-path - сохранил и почистил от лишних тегов - смотрите результат:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 638.571 817.139">
<defs>
 <clipPath id="a">
 <path d="M680.526 821.262l-187.143-1.429-296.429 2.143c-24.424 1.918-32.33-7.176-40-16.428l-2.143-38.572 1.429-750c.805-8.095 1.354-16.19 11.428-24.285l530.715-.715c10.22 2.234 17.954 10.86 20.721 18.658.95 47.352.385 98.005 1.335 142.814-1.037 172.634-1.856 344.061.252 514.365l2.692 7.735c23.333 16.97 46.666 29.21 70 38.571l-34.286 16.429-40 5-3.571 67.857c-16.074 18.023-24.513 18.455-35 17.857z" fill="none" stroke="#000"/></clipPath>
 </defs>
  <image
     transform="matrix(.9312 0 0 .96057 -98.37 8.902)"
     clip-path="url(#a)"
  y="2.929"
  x="-287.024"
     xlink:href="http://www.setwalls.ru/download.php?file=201304/1920x1080/setwalls.ru-4866.jpg"
  preserveAspectRatio="none"
  height="817.139"
  width="1228.8"
  image-rendering="optimizeQuality"/>
</svg>
```

> на всякий случай, если вдруг код в сниппете не будет работать я
>   поместил SVG на специальный сервис : https://jsfiddle.net/fte217j0/3/

для наглядности скриншот

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]